# Use "logger" to log into separate logfile

Tags: linux, bash, shell, logging, raspberry-pi

I'm running a tiny script to autostart a node.js-service on my raspberry pi.
For that reason, I call it from the end of my /etc/rc.local just before the exit 0.

The script is starting, no problem.

Now, my script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Node.js starting..."
LOGFILE=log_`date +%b%d%H%M%S`.log
sudo /opt/node/bin/node /home/pi/www/js/script.js > /home/pi/node_logs/$LOGFILE
```

But I want to use logger instead. I gave it a try but fails.
Can anybody explain to me how to "bind" logger to log only the output of node.js into this logfile? I guess I really misunderstood the way logger works as I'm really not a Linux-pro :-/

Comment: What functionality of `logger` are you trying to use? And what do you mean by it "fails?"

Comment: I guess I was too unspecific.
A new logfile should be created and every message send by node should appear timestamped.

       now=$(date +"%d_%m_%Y_bei_%H_%M_%S")
       sudo /opt/node/bin/node /home/pi/www/js/script.js | adddate > /home/pi/node_logs/$now

this is how I do it right now. But how does it work with logger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`logger` only logs to the syslog - if you really want to do things this way, then you would have to first edit your `syslog.conf` file and add something like this:

```
# node.js logging
local5.*                                                /home/pi/logs/nodejs.log
```

`local5` is a predefined *facility*, make sure it is not in use elsewhere in your syslog conf. Now you need to restart the syslog service:

```
/etc/init.d/syslog stop; /etc/init.d/syslog start
```

And now you can use `logger` to log your messages:

```
sudo /opt/node/bin/node /home/pi/www/js/script.js | logger -p local5.info
```

To have a different log file for each date, you would have to use something like `logrotate`.

An alternative (better) solution would be to prepend the timestamp to each line before you log it:

```
while read msg; do
    echo -n "[$(date +"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")] " >> "$LOGFILE"
    echo "$msg" >> "$LOGFILE"
done < <(sudo /opt/node/bin/node /home/pi/www/js/script.js)
```

Comment: I did it like you noted in your alternative solution. But the first way also works. But you´re right, your alternative is better. Thanks!!